# Why does this code only output lines that I made a replacement on?

Tags: powershell, replace

I wrote this code to test out text manipulation. For each line read from my text file I replace tabs/returns/spaces, then I check if the line contains the carachters 'SAAS' and remove an A. I then write the content to an new file.

The issue is that the new file contains only lines that I made a replacement on and deletes any other lines of text from the orinal file when writing to the new file.

```
$Text = Get-Content -Path C:\Desktop\Phones\Phones_1.txt |
ForEach-Object {($_ -replace '\n','')} |
ForEach-Object {($_ -replace '\r','')} |
ForEach-Object {($_ -replace '\s','')} |
ForEach-Object {IF($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'SAAS'){$_ -replace 'SAAS','SAS'}}
$Text | Out-File 'C:\Desktop\Phones\phone2.txt'
```

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with your `Select-String` function, which I don't believe needs to be there. Also, you can chain together replace statements greatly reducing the need to keep piping your code. I don't think it causes any issues, but you don't need to wrap your `ForEach-Object` blocks in braces either. Here's what that would look like:

```
$Text = Get-Content -Path C:\Desktop\Phones\Phones_1.txt |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\n','' -replace '\r','' -replace '\s','' -replace 'SAAS','SAS' }
$Text | Out-File 'C:\Desktop\Phones\phone2.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

As `$Text` contains an array of single lines, replacing `\r`,`\n` is pretty useless.

You should provide an example of your input and expected output by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56192735/edit)ing your question.

Using a RegularExpression with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(Get-Content .\Phones_1.txt -raw) -replace '\r|\n|\s|(?<=SA)A(?=S)'|Set-Content Phone2.txt
```

Yields this output from your above questions complete text:

> Iwrotethiscodetotestouttextmanipulation.ForeachlinereadfrommytextfileIreplacetabs/returns/spaces,thenIcheckifthelinecontainsthecarachters'SAS'andremoveanA.Ithenwritethecontenttoannewfile.TheissueisthatthenewfilecontainsonlylinesthatImadeareplacementonanddeletesanyotherlinesoftextfromtheorinalfilewhenwritingtothenewfile.$Text=Get-Content-PathC:\Desktop\Phones\Phones_1.txt|ForEach-Object{($*-replace'\n','')}|ForEach-Object{($*-replace'\r','')}|ForEach-Object{($*-replace'\s','')}|ForEach-Object{IF($*|Select-String-Pattern'SAS'){$_-replace'SAS','SAS'}}$Text|Out-File'C:\Desktop\Phones\phone2.txt'Anyhelpisappriciated.